AWS Cognito post-confirmation and authentication race condition
I have a project where I use AWS Cognito to manage user signup and authentication.
Signup flow:

There is a mobile app which can signup the user via Google and Apple login.
The mobile app request for "authSession" , and it receives accessToken and refreshToken from Cognito
I have a resource server, which is invoked by the mobile app after successful signup.
The resource server extracts the cognito:groups claim from the accessToken and assigns a role for the user.

The problem is: sometimes this cognito:groups claim is not included in the accessToken for the first time. After the user opens the app next time (like 30 mins later) it is working.
I am using the Post confirmation trigger to add each user into a group, called "users". Pre-signup trigger cannot be used for this, since the user do not exist yet.
My resource server sends ACCESS_DENIED errorCode when user has insufficient role (so including the case, when it is missing from the token)
In this context, my strong guess is, that post confirmation Lambda finishes its job later, than the first accessToken is requested, therefore it is not included in the first accessToken, but included in the refreshed ones.
How to resolve this issue? I didn't see any option to force refresh the accessToken. Adding a delay between signu and requesting the first accessToken is an ugly and not a fully-satisfying solution. Is there a better way to handle authorization with this Cognito and resource server archictecture?
